# Wireless/ Hard Wired Internet

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I have an hard wired Arris router through my cable company. I bought a tablet for my daughter and it is wifi compatible. Is there a way that I can use my Arris router for wireless connection?

Comment: There were already many questions about setting up wifi here, you should do a search first

Comment: If your router dosen't do wifi, you can in many cases, with the right software/hardware use a laptop or other wifi capable system as an access point too - I've had good luck with those cheap ralink USB adaptors and the stock firmware.

Comment: If your router does not support WiFi then you need to buy a Wireless Access Point.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the device, Arris makes some modems with WIFI built in and some do not.  To better answer your question, I would need to know a model number.  If your device does support WIFI, there is a guide to configuring it on Arris' website.

https://www.arrisi.com/support/documentation/user_guides/_docs/ARRIS_Router_Setup_Web_GUI_UG.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If the device does not have wireless, but does have a spare ethernet port, all you need is a wireless access point (WAP).  Here is an [example](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833425019).  Simply connect the WAP to the router, some easy configuration, then you are good to go.